Verifying Bitcoin Core - Developer Key Fingerprint Confusion
I downloaded the latest version of Core on my Mac and I'm stuck on step 7 of the verification instructions on the Bitcoin Core website:
7. Bitcoin releases are signed by a number of individuals, each with a unique public key. In order to recognize the validity of signatures, you must use GPG to load these public keys locally. You can find many developer keys listed in the bitcoin-core/guix.sigs repository, which you can then load into your GPG key database.
For example, you could load the key builder-keys/fanquake.gpg by downloading the file as fanquake.gpg and using this command:
gpg --import fanquake.gpg
The output of the command above should say that one key was imported, updated, has new signatures, or remained unchanged.
I've downloaded GPG Keychain, downloaded some .gpg files from the link above and opened them into GPG Keychain. But which ones I choose, how to verify, etc. just hasn't clicked.
In a few cases I matched the Fingerprint of a developer in GPG Keychain to the Fingerprint they posted on their website or social media page. Is that verifying correctly, though?
And is the final step in this section entering "gpg --import fanquake.gpg" (or the name of the file) into my Terminal to verify? If that's the case, I'm still not sure what to verify after entering the command.
Thanks.
